# How can I test an iOS 4 app in XCode 4.5?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

Some of my iPhone users still use iOS 4.3, how can I test my app on iOS Simulator, since the latest XCode version 4.5 doesn't have iOS 4?

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: According to comments on this answer it seems this does NOT work on mountain lion.

1. Go to XCode preferences
2. Go to the 'Downloads' tab
3. Click install next to "iOS 4.3 simulator"
4. The iOS 4.3 simulator option should be added to your devices.

:)

[image: 4.3 Simulator in SCode 4.5]

Comment: The oldest simulator available in Xcode 4.5 is the 5.0 simulator.

Comment: My XCode only shows iOS 5, 5.1 and 6. My guess is that you may have upgraded from a previous XCode that included the install files for iOS 4.3?

Comment: Can 4.3 simulator be installed into XCode 4.5?

Comment: Ah it must be Mountain Lion, I wouldn't have thought that would be an issue, I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @JuanSalcedo It definitely is not an upgrade, see previous comments re OSX issues.

Answer (score 0):

it can't be possible to install iOS4 in xcode 4.5, if you need to install the iOS4 simulator then download and install older xcode in separate folder.